# Coloring the background of a (selected) List-Row in Swift-UI in a MacOS App

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit, swiftui-list

I want to set the backgroundcolor of a row in a list in SwiftUI in MacOS.
That works in principle fine with the modifier `.listRowBackground`.

How can I set the color for the (light-gray) left edge of a selected row (see arrow in screenshot).
[image]

Interestingly, the left edge of a selected row is this light-gray, if clicking on "some Text".
Clicking on the free space in the row, the left edge is blue (see screenshot 2).
[image].
Any ideas, where the difference comes from and more important, how I can set a color for this 'edge' of the selected row?

Here is, what I tried:

```
struct SimpleListColorTest2: View {
  @State var sel :Int? = 3
  var body: some View {
    List(selection: $sel) {
      SimpleColoredLine2(lineNr:0, selection: $sel).tag(0)
      SimpleColoredLine2(lineNr:1, selection: $sel).tag(1)
      SimpleColoredLine2(lineNr:2, selection: $sel).tag(2)
      SimpleColoredLine2(lineNr:3, selection: $sel).tag(3)
      SimpleColoredLine2(lineNr:4, selection: $sel).tag(4)
      SimpleColoredLine2(lineNr:5, selection: $sel).tag(5)
    }
  }
}

struct SimpleColoredLine2: View {
  var lineNr : Int
  @Binding var selection : Int?
  var body: some View {
    HStack {
      Text("X2: ").background(Color.yellow)
      Text("some Text").background(Color.yellow)
    }
    .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
      print("Line clicked")
      selection = lineNr
    })
    .listRowBackground(selection == lineNr ? Color.red :Color.clear)
  }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Another approach is to use `ScrollView` instead of a `List`. You can select items by tapping on each CellView you created with `.onTapGesture { ... }` modifier and saving the state.